# How to broadcast to other controllers when load with module.config or .run in Angularjs

Tags: module, angularjs, config, factory, broadcast

I have a checking when reading the web page,then using the result to refresh sidebar by ng-repeat,but I have errors  :

Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $scope from myModule   or
Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $scope from sharedService

How can I resolve it?

Here is my code

module:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
```

service for broadcast:

```
myModule.factory('mySharedService', function($rootScope) { //service
    var sharedService = {};

    sharedService.keyHistory = [];
    sharedService.linkHistory = [];
    sharedService.prepForBroadcast = function(key,link) {
        this.keyHistory = key;
        this.linkHistory = link;
        this.broadcastItem();
    };

    sharedService.prepForBroadcastAdd =function(key){
        console.log(this.keyHistory.push(key));
        //this.linkHistory = linkHistory+link;
        this.broadcastItem();
    };

    sharedService.broadcastItem = function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('handleBroadcast');
    };

    return sharedService;
});
```

config to do Checking:

```
myModule.config(function($scope,sharedService){

        $.ajax({
            url:"/fly/AJAX",
            type:"POST",
            contentType:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',     
            datatype:"json",
            success:function(data){
                if(data!=null){
                var loginResult = $.parseJSON(data);


                if (loginResult.success == true){ 
                    console.log("login success");
                    $("#userLable").html(loginResult.userName+'('+loginResult.loginID+')');//
                    if (loginResult.hasHistory==true) {  
                        sharedService.prepForBroadcast(loginResult.searchHistory,[]);
                        console.log("broadcast");
                    }
                    };
                }
            }
    });

});
```

SideCtrl:

```
function SideCtrl($scope,sharedService) {
    $scope.$on('handleBroadcast', function() {

    $scope.keyHistory =sharedService.keyHistory;
    $scope.linkHistory = sharedService.linkHistory;
    });        

}

SideCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', 'mySharedService'];
```

THX !

Comment: Config blocks don't have a scope.

Comment: Thx for your reply sir!
Can you tell me how to modify my code?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here. That's why I gave such a short answer. :-) Why are you using `$.ajax` instead of `$http`? Other than broadcast an event, what do you want your service to do?

Comment: In fact,I have 3 controllers,I hope they can communicate to each other by service .
This is my reference http://jsfiddle.net/VxafF/ and it do work.                     Now I am trying add an checking when this web page loaded,so I use config to try this ,this is my fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/deltaguita/YnACF/  :)

Comment: Using a service to communicate with multiple controllers is the right approach, but I don't think using `broadcast` is. Before I post an answer - will the data be fetched only that once, initially? Or will it be requested again later?

Comment: I hope the data can be used many times later because user may update it  :)

Comment: I meant does the AJAX request need to occur more than once?

Comment: Check do ajax once when initially webpage.
If user user Login another ID,it will do another AJAX check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is due to trying to request a `$scope` in a config block, which you can't do. If I understand what you're trying to do, then I also think you're over-complicating it. I'd solve the problem a little differently. The details would depend on your requirements and use case, but based on the information you gave...

I'd have a service responsible for communication with the server and storing the state:

```js
app.factory( 'loginService', function ( $http ) {
  var result;

  function doRequest( data ) {
    // just flesh out this post request to suit your needs...
    return $http.post( '/fly/ajax', data, {} )
    .then( function ( response ) {
      // assuming you don't care about the headers, etc.
      return response.data;
    });
  }

  // Do it once initially
  if ( ! angular.isDefined( result ) ) {
    result = doRequest();
  }

  // return the service's public API
  return {
    getStatus: function () { return result; },
    login: doRequest
  };
});
```

Now the first time this service is requested, the `$http` request will be made. If you're accessing this from multiple controllers, the post will only occur once because of the `isDefined` statement. You can then use this in your controllers:

```js
app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function( $scope, loginService ) {
  loginService.getStatus().then( function ( data ) {
    // do whatever you need to with your data. 
    // it is only guaranteed to exist as of now, because $http returns a promise
  });
});
```

Every controller accesses it the same way, but it was still only called once! You can set values against the scope and access it from your views, if you want:

```js
app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function( $scope, loginService ) {
  loginService.getStatus().then( function ( data ) {
    $scope.loginId = data.loginID;
  });
});
```

And in your view:

```html
<h1>Welcome, {{loginId || 'guest'}}!</h1>
```

And if you need to, you call the function again:

```js
app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function( $scope, loginService ) {
  // ...
  loginService.login( $scope.user ).then( function ( data ) {
    $scope.loginId = data.loginID;
  });
  // ...
});
```

As you can see, broadcasting an event is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you sir!
It do work very well in my project.Could I have another question? Why the ng-repeat dose not show data as  {{loginId || 'guest'}} When init? They show data when I change or click the table only, this is my fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/deltaguita/YcyQU/

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing it run. Can you send me a working fiddle?

Comment: Well,server works on localhost,I don't know how to deploy it on fiddle...   XD

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently. I would create some sort of more top-level controller, like `function MainController($rootScope, $scope, sharedService)` and wire it up with body: `<body ng-controller='mainController' ng-init='init()'`. After that you should create `init()` method in `MainController`.

Inside this initialization method I would call `sharedService` which should make AJAX request (via `$http`! that's the best practice, and it's very similar to jQuery) and broadcast proper event when required.

That way you make sure to call initialization just once (when `MainController` is initializing), you stick to the angular's best practices and avoid dodgy looking code.